# Cannot remove box border

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I've tried to see the "view" tab, but I don't think I see something relevant though, it was fine yesterday.

I've tried "no border" but it still isn't removed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I hide text boundaries?

Go to **File** > **Options** > **Advanced** and uncheck **Show text boundaries**:

[image]

Source [How to show or hide text boundaries in Word?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/945-word-show-hide-text-boundaries.html)